# ValueError: arrays must all be same length during getting price

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my code. I'm trying to get product names with their prices together. But they don't have same length. len(pricesList) == 18 / len(namesList) == 19. It's ok. I know the problem. For more details please scroll down.

```
import math
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import unicodecsv as csv
import time
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from csv import reader

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\ain01tr\Desktop\Çalışma Dosyası\Python\Projeler\Getting Price\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.elryan.com/en/search?q=jelly")
namesList = []
pricesList = []
names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mb0.cl-accent.mt10.product-name")
for name in names:
    namesList.append(name.text)
prices = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".price-regular.lh30.cl-primary.weight-700")
for price in prices:
    pricesList.append(price.text)
    
data = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : namesList, 'Price': pricesList})
```

I've tried to solve the problem with code below:

```
#a = {'Name' : namesList,'Price': pricesList}
#data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
#data.transpose()
```

It worked. But this is not a kind of data what I want. NaN price is automatically going to last index so it's not correct. How can I fix this?

I hope my explaination is ok. I'm new at this platform.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your locator is not taking "special" price. dont you need it or you are skipping it because you dont know how to create such locator?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I realized the reason because of you. Special or normal. Doesnt matter. it is not a big deal for me. How can I fix this skipping thing?

Comment: That's the primary reason of price mismatch. Anyway, your problem statement is not clear. You mentioned "I've tried to solve the problem with code below:", what problem, you tried to solve? Layman term, what is your expected output and what is your actual output? What is the problem in actual output? This kind of information will give more clarity.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @QualityMatters thank you for your support I solved the problem. My main problem was price mismatch. I got my data correctly.

Comment: @Adofalcon You can share your solution so rest of the community can also get benefitted with that

Answer (score 0):

BEFORE

```
prices = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".price-regular.lh30.cl-primary.weight-700")
for price in prices:
pricesList.append(price.text)
```

AFTER

```
prices = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".lh30.cl-primary.weight-700")
for price in prices:
pricesList.append(price.text)
```